# Lost all history, bookmarks and extensions after Google Chrome was automatically updated

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, history

Google Chrome (browser) was automatically updated to version 39.0.2171.99 when I was not at my desk and now I have lost all my history and bookmarks and extensions. Is this revertible? I truly dislike this version showing my email at the top right corner and it being synced with my gmail account.

Comment: What if you log out? (Maybe your history and all is not linked to the account that is currently logged in.) Before trying anything, ensure to FIRST backup the folder `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"` and ALL its sub folders.

Comment: Your email was always visible.  It might have taken more work.  But it was still highly visible.

Comment: Gigili, any chance this only happened after you tried to remove the account/profile icon? (I vaguely remember having run into that some months ago, when messing with [these settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2TK5.png), but then I simply restored a backup and never investigated any further.)

Comment: @Arjan: I am not sure but I signed out of the account shown there and when I signed in again, bookmarks extensions and history was gone!

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine just ran into the same problem. Well, to your data it is most likely that it is lost. But to be sure you can check out

> %localappdata%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"\Default\

and look for a Bookmark file. There could be a file named:

> Bookmark.bak.

This should be the backup file. Try to rename it into Bookmark and hope that they appear.
If you want to remove the profile manager in the right top corner you can do it by typing chrome://flags. There should be a category named something like New profil administrative system. Disable it and restart chrome and voila it should be removed.

Comment: Maybe there are even other folders in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\"User Data"` which apply to different profiles. Backup all first, and then try to log out of the browser?

Comment: @Arjan depending on that he has different profiles he should do that. Google did some weird things on this update. Maybe chrome doesn't recognize anymore that his data is located within %localappdata%.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did find the bookmark file, but I am not sure how to restore it, could you help?

Comment: Renaming didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Signing in to Chrome restored my bookmarks, most likely this stuff is now stored on Google's server to make them available on different computers if required. :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you did not synced your bookmarks you won't be able to restore them by signing in.

There is an additional way to restore Chrome, is going to the directory:

C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Google\

Then select and right-click the Folder/Directory "Chrome", once you
   selected it, click on Properties.

Inside "Chrome Properties" go to the Tab "Previous Versions" go to an
   earlier date before you remember your bookmarks disappearing, select
   it, click the Button "Restore".

Wait for about 10 to 25 mins and when you open Chrome your Bookmarks
   will be back.

Now make a Backup, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Due to an over-aggressive system cleaner utility I lost all my Firefox tabs, bookmarks, history, etc.

I tried the solutions listed above without success, and then tried running a System Restore, which is included in all current Windows versions.

I restored the system to the date I ran the cleaner utility and all of my bookmarks, history, and even my previous browser session with all the tabs came right back!

So, if nothing else works, try System Restore. It'll probably be in your Control Panel listed under Backup and Restore.

Answer (score 0):

[Understand structure of Chrome User Profile data to Transfer to new PC/ OS & avoid Settings corruption Error?](https://superuser.com/questions/951095/understand-structure-of-chrome-user-profile-data-to-transfer-to-new-pc-os-avo)

Google (Android, Apple & Microsoft and various companies) has got into pushing Updates down our throats, which many times destroy/ damage our "working" environments.

Although we may work on blocking them, it seems rather difficult on a longer term basis.

Getting to specifics of Chrome User Profile Data (that you lost).

For future reference the only way around this is to backup, copy and understand the Chrome User Profile and the various things it contains; especially important data that we assume will be safe inside Extensions and Bookmarks and so on.

I started a rather solo effort & extensive research in this direction with lot of details about how Chrome operates/ stores the User Profile Data, but no easily available conclusion or answer / solution that still works perfectly.